# comparing two attribute value in component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration, aura-if

I have loop in which i want to compare  `rec.id`  with  arrtribute `SummaryId1` which is integer.when i use  `==` operator like that  `<aura:if isTrue="{!v.summaryId1  ==  !recc.id}">` then its not working. i debuged both  have value.  please check the below code

```
<aura:attribute name="summaryId1" type="Integer"/>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.Recipes}" var="recc" indexVar="index">
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.summaryId1  ==  !recc.id}">
                              
 {!v.summaryId1}
 </aura:if>
```

`SummaryId1`  value is one of  `recc.id` value. when i use  `!=`  in IF condition  then its  display the value but i want to work when it same. What i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The merge field syntax is `{!...}`. Note the `!` at the beginning. Anywhere else in the merge field, `!` means "not", which means that you're inverting the value of `recc.Id`, which will then presumably always equal `false`, because any non-empty value is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), and the `not` of anything truthy is `false`. Do not prefix variables/attributes with `!` unless you intend to negate their values.

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.summaryId1 == recc.id}">
```

If you have a habit of forgetting this, try writing your expressions with some space on each side:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{! v.summaryId1 == recc.id }">
```

This makes it visually clear as to what you're doing, I think, and I'd recommend getting into the habit of that if it will help you.

Comment: i used ``recc.id`` but still not working with  ==  operator  .  when i used  != then it display . don't know why?

Comment: recc.id  values --> ``
641803
73420
640352
157103
157111
674272
775666
632572
632471``      summaryId1  value--> ``641803``

Comment: first value is same but still not working

Comment: @Fawadazam Maybe the id values are strings, not numbers? `641803 !== '641803'` (strict equality check).

Comment: Yes  got it ....Solved

Comment: the one value is in Integer and other is String ....thanks  you so much